# Is there something similar to hackage for SML?

Tags: sml, hackage

Since the language is fully standardized, that would be a quite useful resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

**22 Oktober 2011**

As of lately, planning of a package "system" of some kind is emerging. The [smackage](https://github.com/standardml/hackday/wiki/Smackage) Wiki at the [standardml](https://github.com/standardml) github repository contains the initial thoughts.

---

Not that I'm aware of.

However the MLton guys have a quite nice svn repository with cool stuff in it, called [MLtonLibraryProject](http://mlton.org/MLtonLibraryProject) ([svn webview](http://mlton.org/cgi-bin/viewsvn.cgi/mltonlib/)). Though it has been a while since someone posted any code there

You might wan't to look at [myLib](https://github.com/mortenbp/mylib) or [sml-ext](https://github.com/seanmcl/sml-ext)

Besides that you can find various stuff spread out all over the internet. However almost all of what you will find depends on the implementer's personal extensions of the basis library(that also goes for most of the MLtonLibraryProject.